# How to protect against cross domain http requests? (server side)

Tags: php, http, cross-domain

I've read some questions on SO about denying cross domain requests but all just state to rely on the client side protection ( same origin policy ) . Are there any layers of protection that can be done server side ? Should i rely on header- origin , header - referer ? Some say header referer get's modified by some anti-spyware programs . Some say ff doesint include origin header option (but it does) , some say chrome doesnt and so on :) .
  I know headers can be modified (referer can be modified even with setrequestheader method) , but , if you ever done any protection server side for this matter please share any ideeas .

P.S. : A possibility would be to tokenise each request (all type of requests , requests that only get data , requests that change data on server etc ) but that would be a pain in the ass ...

P.P.S. : omg don't spam about synchroniser token pattern ... as i said in the firs P.S. yea that would be a solution , any other ideeas?

Comment: Session management is a good way to protect against cross domain requests.

Comment: @scuzzy please be more specific .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mayor question is against which kind of attacks you want protect?

If you want protect against CSRF, then you need process form with random security token.

Like

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="random value generated on server side for each request" />
```

After form will submitted you need compare token from request and token stored in session on server side.

If you want deny load some kind of resources from other domains (like loading images or scripts on evil.com from you server), then you can add to each resource similar token.

Like

```
<img src="/images/mysuperimg.png?token=<token>" />
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have heard of [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)?

here's an overview CSRF works and how it's prevented:

anyone can request a page from your site, the same way anyone can also POST on your site. let's say you have a registration form. one can copy your form, and put in any HTML page, remove the JS validations, and spam you infinitely. sounds like a threat right?

however, you can prevent this by using a session id. this is a unique string (usually MD5 or SHA-1), that is stored on a session variable in PHP before rendering the page. this session id is also rendered in a hidden input form on your form. now when the form is submitted, PHP checks if that session id sent with the form is a match with a the session id stored in the session variable. if it's valid, you proceed, and the one stored in the server is nullified so that it wont be reused.

also, if a certain time has elapsed, that session id should expire. so lets say if a user has lingered on a form for more than your 15 min expiry. using that form will be invalid. you'd have to refresh the page to get a new session id

---

now you might ask how to use this on page requests rather than forms?

i know of [2 ways to send over session ids to the server](http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php), and that is either by cookie or via appending your sessionid in the url.

for cookie, it works the same way. if your page is generated by your server, the page creates the session id on your server and sends a copy as a cookie. the next page request, you read the cookie of the request, get it's session id, compare with the one on the server, and if equal, request is valid, you proceed. otherwise, it's invalid.

for those who have disabled cookies, you can append the sessionid in the url of every link you have on the page. notice that on some sites, they have a url parameter of `sid`, or `sessid` and so on? that's how they pass it. every link in your page will be appended this id. and upon clicking the link, all the server does is get that session id from the url, and compare it with the server.

quite long answer :D

Comment: ty for your long answer :) added P.P.S. :)